# how to change html content which is loaded inside other html 's body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading one html page in other, lets say, `home.html` is called inside `index.html` but now I wanted to change some content of `home.html` with the help of java script or jquery inside of `index.html`
below is what I've tried so far

**index.html**

```
   <html>
    <body> </body>
</html>
<script>
    $('body').load('home.html');
    // below div **session_error** is from home.html page,I wanted to change its text on this page
           $('#session_error').html("This is session out errror");

</script>
```

Comment: Is it `session-error` or `session_error`? Seems there is a typo

Comment: `load` has a callback.  `$('body').load('home.html', function() {//do stuff here });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.load()` call is asynchronous.  So you need to wait for it to be done before making changes.

something like:

```
$('body').load('home.html', function() {
   $('#session_error').html("This is session out errror");
});
```